# Clean implementation of storing current row index

Tags: c#, datatable, implementation

I need to find out what the current Row index from within a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (DataRow row in DataTable[0].Rows)
{
    // I do stuff in here with the row, and if it throws an exception
    // I need to pass out the row Index value to the catch statement
}
```

An exception can occur at any point within the `try/catch` block, but if I use an incremental counter within the `foreach` loop, and the exception occurs outside of the loop, I'll get an invalid row because I've moved the pointer along by one.

I know that I can declare a `DataRow` outside of the `foreach` scope, but the `foreach` is within a `try/catch` block.  I need to pass the Row index so I can use it in the `catch` statement.  I should say that my `DataTable` is at class level scope.

Is this really the only way to get the current Row index?  Or is there a cleaner implementation?

**EDIT**

So, giving more thought to this, I could use an `int` to store the current row value, and increment this value like so:

```
int i = 0;

try
{
    // Some code here - which could throw an exception
    foreach (DataRow row in DataTables[0].Rows)
    {
        // My stuff
        i++;
    }
    // Some code here - which could throw an exception
}
catch
{
    // Use the counter
    DataRow row = DataTables[0].Rows[i];
}
```

However, if the `foreach` doesn't throw the exception, then the value of `i` will be greater than the actual number of rows in the table.  Obviously, I could do `i--;` after the `foreach` loop, but this seems like a *really* dirty hack.

Comment: Declare a counter variable outside the `try` and increment for every loop iteration.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this, just incase there was a fancy indexer that could be used.  It maybe my only solution though. :o(

Comment: Sometimes a plain for() loop works better than for-each.  This is one of those cases.

Comment: Think about what it means if you get an exception _after_ the loop exits. Then the index is meaningless as it wasn't a specific row that caused the issue. I would set the counter to an invalid value (say `-1`) and in the `catch` do something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a dirty way is to whrap it in an additional trycatch block:

```
int i = 0;
try
{
    // Some code here - which could throw an exception

    try{
        foreach (DataRow row in DataTables[0].Rows)
        {
            // My stuff
            i++;
        }
        // Some code here - which could throw an exception
    }
    catch{
      i--;
      throw;
    }

}
catch
{
    // Use the counter
    DataRow row = DataTables[0].Rows[i];
}
```

that way you surely know that the exception is thrown right affter the foreach or durring it, and you always get the correct iterator.

Comment: I ended up doing a similar solution to this.

Comment: @NeilKnight well, that is dirty, but then again now you have full control over this exception. BTW, now that I think about it, if you separate the types of the exceptions, you could use multiple catch blocks. I mean, if your foreach statement generate only NullRefferenceException, you could catch it separately and decrement the "i" variable. that would be a bit cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a counter variable outside the try and increment for every loop iteration:

```
int counter = 0;

try
{
    foreach (DataRow row in DataTable[0].Rows)
    {
        // Do stuff
        counter++
    }

    counter = -1;
    // Do other stuff
}
catch
{
    // Counter has index
    if (counter == -1)
    {
       // exception did not occur in loop
    }
    else
    {
       // exception did occur in loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this won't help because if an exception occurs after the `foreach` then I have the incorrect row number.

Comment: @NeilKnight - Your description of the issue is not correct is this case. You actually say that the exception is thrown within the `foreach` (in the comment block).

Comment: I actually say that "if it throws an exception", an exception can occur anywhere within the `try/catch` block.

Comment: @NeilKnight - OK. But the comment about the exception is in a `foreach`, my assumption was that this will happen in the `foreach`. Can you please edit your question and add detail to it - if you are doing things _outside_ the `foreach` that may throw an exception, please explain how an index will help - an index of _what_?